# Adding and removing items from a list fails in c#

Tags: c#

I have several dynamic textboxes and whenever the textbox loses focus i would like to add its text value to a list and remove when the textbox is cleared

```
<TextBox LostFocus="comment_box_LostFocus" Name="comment_box" Tag="{x:Bind id}" Width="300"/>
```

Now on the c# code

```
List<CommentModel> commentlist = new List<CommentModel>();

private void comment_box_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var comenttext = ((TextBox)sender).Text; //this is okay
    var commentid = ((TextBox)sender).Tag; //this is okay

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(comenttext)) //incase user clears the textbox
    {
        for(var i=0; i< commentlist.Count; i++)
        {
            if(commentlist[i].id == (int)commentid)
            {
                var itemToRemove = commentlist.Single(r => r.id == (int)commentid);
                commentlist.Remove(itemToRemove);
            }
        }
    }
    else //add new or update incase its a comment change
    {  
        for (var i = 0; i < commentlist.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((commentlist[i].id) == ((int)commentid))
            {
                commentlist[i].comment = comenttext;
            }
            else
            {
                 commentlist.Add(new CommentModel((int)commentid, (string)comenttext));
            }
        }
        }

            if (commentlist.Count == 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Comment list is empty adding initial comment");
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(comenttext))
                {
                    //automatically add new
                    commentlist.Add(new CommentModel((int)commentid, (string)comenttext));
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The class CommentModel is

```
class CommentModel
{
    public int id;
    public string comment;

    public CommentModel(int idval, string commentval)
    {
        this.id = idval;
        this.comment = commentval;
    }
}
```

Whenever i try

```
for(var i=0; i< commentlist.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(commentlist[i].comment);
}
```

The is double duplication of comments That is

```
first entry: "test one", debug output "test one", 
second entry :"no2", debug output :"test one", "no2"....
```

Where could i be going wrong?

Comment: I can't see how you get any entries in your list in the first instance - if the text box is not empty, then you go into the else clause in the if statement in the lost focus event, but you never get into the loop as commentList.Count = 0, so you never add anything to the list. If you are adding entries to the list - then this must be done somewhere else.

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with a debugger?

Comment: @PaulF Sorry i forgot to add the last part in the question, ive updated the question

Comment: @pm100 am seeing duplications in the final commentlist List which reall confuses, eg 1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4.... such kind of duplications

Comment: I'm not sure I see the need for "//incase user clears the textbox". A few too many IF's. Focusing on cleaning/refactoring the code will ultimately reveal the answer.

Comment: @TezWingfield the //incase user clears textbox is necessary since i would like to remove that comment from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code to something like this :

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(comenttext)) //incase user clears the textbox
{
    for (var i = 0; i < commentlist.Count; i++)
    {
        if (commentlist[i].id == (int)commentid)
        {
            var itemToRemove = commentlist.Single(r => r.id == (int)commentid);
            commentlist.Remove(itemToRemove);
            break;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    bool found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < commentlist.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((commentlist[i].id) == ((int)commentid))
        {
            commentlist[i].comment = comenttext;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (! found)
        commentlist.Add(new CommentModel((int)commentid, (string)comenttext));
}
```

In you original code you iterate through each element in the list, if the id's match you update the comment, if not you always add another entry - so you will end up with multiple duplicate entries.

You need to search the list & only add if the entry is not found, if the id is found then you can stop searching the list.

Similarly, you can exit the loop after find the entry in the if clause, but in that case you will only be wasting time, as you have already removed the entry for the id

A shorter LINQ solution without for loops could be :

```
var itemInList = commentlist.Where(li => li.id == (int)commentid).FirstOrDefault();
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(comenttext)) //incase user clears the textbox
{
  if (itemInList != null)
    commentlist.Remove(itemInList);
}
else //add new or update incase its a comment change
{
  if (itemInList != null)
    itemInList.comment = comenttext;
  else
    commentlist.Add(new CommentModel((int)commentid, comenttext));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulF, this now woks

Comment: Glad to be of help - you should mark my answer as correct, in case anyone else has a similar problem.